# AS3: draw 2d DisplayObjects UNDER stage3ds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any way to draw 2d DisplayObjects UNDER stage3ds? I mean, flash' stage is allways upper stage3ds:
[image]
Can I create another stage below Stage3D[0]? Or any other way?

Comment: IIRC no, the order of stages is fixed.

Comment: There's no other way no. Besides Stage3D are not transparent anyway.